# jQuery AJAX with text and file input in one call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do you pass both text input as well as a file in one jQuery AJAX call?
The code I have below passes the text input fields well but the file input returns an error (see below).

```
var formData = new FormData();

    formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'superheroAlias'    : $('input[name=superheroAlias]').val()
    };

    formData.append('profile_pic', $('input[id="profile_pic"]')[0].files[0]);

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : 'process.php', 
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        encode      : true
    })
```

On trying to receive the request on the PHP end like this:

```
$target_dir = "image_uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir .rand(1,999). basename(str_replace(" ","",$_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"]));
```

I get the following error:

> Undefined index: profile_pic

I have checked out a couple of solutions here on Stack Overflow already but none has done the trick for me yet.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php Duplicated question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Comment: formData.append('name', $('input[name=name]').val())

formData.append('email', $('input[name=email]').val())
formData.append('superheroAlias', $('input[name=superheroAlias]').val())

Comment: Shouldn't you set somewhere the enctype to "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: @Amarnasan, the form already has that parameter

Comment: Sorry, can't see that parameter used in your code.

Comment: @Cosmin_Victor, the example you reference only includes the file, mine is a mix of both file and text fields

Comment: @Amarnasan, You're totally right. I can't believe I spent hours thinking I had already done that bit. I've simply added this: formData.append('profile_pic', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); and it now works. If you want, you can put your comment as a solution and I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just bind submit listener for your form and pass form data to your ajax automatically like below:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this); 

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : 'process.php', 
        data        : formData, 
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        encode      : true
    })

})
```